# Writing a function to add or modify an existing object inside an array

Tags: javascript, array

I have an array of objects. Each object has two properties, `id` and `quantity`.

I wrote a function to add an object to the array. But the function must check if the object already exists within the array. If it does exist the function must increment the `quantity` property. Otherwise it must add a new object.

Is there an idiomatic way to achieve the same result? I feel that looping over the array to compare the id of the object at index against the id passed as argument is not the right approach.

I am also suspicious of the `found = false` temporary variable.

Finally, in Ruby we are encouraged to break down long methods into smaller ones. I am aware that JavaScript is not the same, but I feel that this could be further refactored.

```
addItem = function(id, items) {
  var found, i;
  found = false;
  i = 0;
  while (i < items.length) {
    if (id === items[i].id) {
      items[i].quantity++;
      found = true;
      break;
    }
    i++;
  }
  if (!found) {
    return items.push({
      id: id,
      quantity: 1
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also don't like the `found` variable, I think you should extract that part to a `indexOf` method to return the index of the item you want to change, as you only seem to want to do `items[i].quantity++;` once. This way you can `return` the index directly. I would also use a `for` loop rather than `while`, as you're looping through a fixed number of items.

```
indexOf = function(id, items) {
  var i = 0;
  var len = items.length;
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (id === items[i].id) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

This way you can call your `indexOf` function from your `addItem` function and check if the return value is -1, if it is then you call `items.push`, if it's not -1 then you perform `items[index].quantity++;`.

Instead of using an array structure, you could use more of a `Set` structure, which can be implemented in JavaScript as seen in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042886/set-data-structure-of-java-in-javascript-jquery), assuming that your `id` can easily be converted to a string.

Comment: Thanks. `id` is already a string. Can I ask you why a `for` loop is preferred to a `while` loop?

Comment: Also, doesn't adding this method now require two loops? I would still need the loop inside the `addItem` method to increment the quantity at index, right?

Comment: @JumbalayaWanton When you iterate over an array index-by-index, programmers are more used to for-loops. Technically they have about the same performance, but for-loop is more compact, as the initialization, condition-check and increment is done on the same line.

Comment: @JumbalayaWanton No, you don't need to use a loop inside `addItem`, just increment the quantity at the index stored in the `index` variable (that you retreived from the `indexOf` function), as long as that index is >= 0 (meaning that a match was found).

Answer (score 9):

Why are you using an array to do the job of a map? Use the right data structures....

... instead, use a hashmap (associative array) of `[id, quantity]`. If `id` exists in hashmap, then increment up the value at `hashmap[id]`.

Comment: Brief answers which do not explain why a suggestion is better are often converted to comments on CodeReview. I have taken the liberty of expressing why this 'obvious' suggestion is better than what the oP has... please feel free to revise if you want to.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this answer. Do you mean to create a hash or arrays? Like `{[1, 1], [2, 1]}` etc...?

Comment: @JumbalayaWanton - [see this quick blog about it](http://blog.xkoder.com/2008/07/10/javascript-associative-arrays-demystified/)

Comment: @rolfl OK. I think I understand. I could use `{ id: [id, quantity] }`... so, assuming ids 1 and 2, with values 1 and 1 respectively, I would do `{ 1: [1, 1], 2: [2, 1] }`. Then I can check for the presence of the id in the hash... sorry to sound like a dunce, but this is new stuff for me.

Comment: You don't need the array as the value, just the quantity:  `{ "1": 1, "2": 1, "3": 1, ... }`.  Then your `addItem` function is simply `addItem = function(id, items) { if (items[id]) items[id]++; else items[id] = 1; }`

Comment: @david yes, thank you, in particular for `if (item[id])`. I had figured that out (that I did not need the array). I have other properties that I omitted; and if I wish to use them I will need an array.

Comment: This is essentially the same thing that I say in the bottom of my answer, where I link to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042886/set-data-structure-of-java-in-javascript-jquery) that shows how it can be done.

Comment: @JumbalayaWanton Thanks, in the end though I strongly recommend that you go with the Set/Map approach that the SO question shows.

Comment: and what to do if you need the keys in sorted order, I am storing time series where I can get multiple updates to the same timestamp or I can get a new timestamp

Answer (score 7):

I don't really like that found flag. Also using while or for loops ads a bit of extra code to write to get the value of an arrays items.  I would use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method for this case.

```
addItem = function(id, items) {
  var foundItem = items.filter(function(item) {
    return item.id === id;
  })[0];

  if (foundItem) {
    foundItem.quantity++;
  } else {
    //return the new length here cause that is what you did
    return items.push({
      id: id,
      quantity: 1
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the `found` variable. Use `return` when done.

You can also use `for` instead of `while`.

```
addItem = function(id, items) {
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (id === items[i].id) {
      items[i].quantity++;
      return;
    }
  }
  return items.push({
    id: id,
    quantity: 1
  });
};
```